# Prevent files in the public folder to be executed in nest.js

Tags: static, nestjs

I want to prevent the users from executing the files that are in the public folder. In my app, users can upload any type of file, such as.js,.mjs,.ts, .py, or any other file that is possibly available on the web. If some malicious user uploads any executable script file and executes that file, then my app will break, which is something I want to prevent. How can I do that?

my folder structure:

```
- project
    - src
    - node_modules
    - public
    - dist
    - other files...
```

The uploaded files are saved in the public folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app shouldn't break if a malicious script is uploaded, it would break if the malicious script was uploaded and then **executed**. So long as you don't use `exec()` on unknown scripts you should be fine, it's just a text file until it's executed.